# ElectronicHorizon Constructor AccessControlException using HERE-API

Tags: here-api

I receive the following error when calling the ElectronicHorizon constructor.  I have the Freemium Premium SDK and I've already verified that the package name, app id, app code, and license key are correct.  I am already successfully performing routing using CoreRouter.  Is this behavior expected for a freemium account?  Or is it an issue with my implementation

The following is called to start the MapEngine:

```
    MapEngine.getInstance().init(appContext, onEngineInitListener);
```

In the OnEngineInitListener is defined the following:

```
       @Override
        public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
            if (error == Error.NONE) {

                ElectronicHorizon eh = new ElectronicHorizon();

            } else {
            }
        }
```

The following is the offending code:

```
    ElectronicHorizon eh = new ElectronicHorizon();
```

Error:

```
    java.security.AccessControlException: Access to this operation is denied. Contact your HERE representative for more information.
            at com.nokia.maps.MapAccessorImpl.<init>(MapAccessorImpl.java:55)
            at com.here.android.mpa.electronic_horizon.MapAccessor.<init>(MapAccessor.java:28)
            at com.here.android.mpa.electronic_horizon.ElectronicHorizon.<init>(ElectronicHorizon.java:114)
```

Comment: Please try to ask a specific question. Maybe you want to know if this operation is restricted to freemium accounts, or maybe you want to know how to resolve an authentication problem. The question should make this clear. You also should share the code that triggers the error, unless you think it's obvious what operation does it to users of this software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see https://developer.here.com/faqs#payment-subscription

Especially Point 4 in section "Licensing & Terms":

"What other limits apply to my Freemium or Pro plan?

The Electronic Horizon feature in the Premium Mobile SDK is excluded. Please contact us if you're interested in this feature."